# Drupal throwing blank update.php file

Tags: php, drupal-7, updates

I'm updating drupalfrom 7.32 to 7.33

I followed the steps here for updating drupal 7:
https://www.drupal.org/node/1223018

I also followed the step that mentioned to set `$update_free_access` to `TRUE` (temporarily) while updating.

But, when I visit mysite.com/update.php it is still throwing a completely blank page.

I also verified in `settings.php` that:

- the file had the database configuration values
- Verified that actual data still existed in this database.

What gives? Are there any other solutions to fix this ? (Without having to do a complete clean install)

**UPDATE**
Errors in `error.log` are:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required
PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there something in you error log ?

Comment: I take that back, see the errors above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an permissions error. I had, had all files not on 755.

I had files having octets of 600 to 777 and they needed to be changed to 755 with:

```
sudo chmod 755
```

I followed "KeithM"'s advice on directory permissions here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26131/correct-permission-for-site-default-and-files-folders